# Вывод данных json созданного из таблицы с заменяемым содержимым

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть таблица, которая записывается в JSON в local storage

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
       <tr>
      <th scope="row">Координаты</th>
            <td> <div id="mod5" >отсутствует</div> </td>
         </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Название города</th>
      <td>      
      <div id="mod4" >отсутствует</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <th scope="row">Своя надпись</th>
      <td>      
      <div id="mod6" >отсутствует</div></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Шрифт</th>
      <td><div id="mod" >Lobster</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">Размер шрифта</th>
      <td><div id="mod2" >Крупный</div></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <th scope="row">Ориентация</th>
      <td><div id="mod3" >Книжная</div></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Значения в строках меняются и подставляются через js
Проблема в том, что при выводе данных из localstorage получается следующее:

```
[{"Координаты":" <div id=\"mod5\">zoom: 10, location : 59.9342802 , 30.335098600000038</div> ","Название города":"\t\t\n\t <div id=\"mod4\"></div>","Своя надпись":"\t\t\n\t <div id=\"mod6\"></div>","Шрифт":"<div id=\"mod\">Lobster</div>","Размер шрифта":"<div id=\"mod2\">Крупный</div>","Ориентация":"<div id=\"mod3\">Книжная</div>"}]
```

Как можно вывести данные в приличном виде??

Comment: Дак а что вы подразумеваете под приличным видом?

Comment: без скобок и дивов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  let obj = [{"Координаты":" <div id=\"mod5\">zoom: 10, location : 59.9342802 , 30.335098600000038</div> ","Название города":"\t\t\n\t <div id=\"mod4\"></div>","Своя надпись":"\t\t\n\t <div id=\"mod6\"></div>","Шрифт":"<div id=\"mod\">Lobster</div>","Размер шрифта":"<div id=\"mod2\">Крупный</div>","Ориентация":"<div id=\"mod3\">Книжная</div>"}];

  let s = '';
  for (key in obj[0]) {
     s += key + ' : ' + obj[0][key] + '\n';
  }
  console.log(s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').replace(/\t\t\n\t/g,''));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно! Но не понимаю как адаптироват под вывод из локального хранилища, кладу так localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(jsonArr)); Как вывести в таком случае? let obj = ('myStorage') не дает результата

Comment: let obj = localStorage.getItem('myStorage');

Comment: Почему-то выводит   0: [

Comment: Не должно выводить 0) проверьте может в другом месте у вас косяк. Я получаю https://jsfiddle.net/p510tuoy/19/

Comment: Прошу прощения, так не удалось разобраться. Может я неверно вывожу $(document).ready(function(){

  let obj =   localStorage.getItem('myStorage');

  let s = '';
  for (key in obj[0]) {
     s += key + ' : ' + obj[0][key] + '\n';
  }
  console.log(s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').replace(/\t\t\n\t/g,''));
  alert (s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').replace(/\t\t\n\t/g,''))
}); 

Алерт выводит 0

Comment: Вот полный код https://jsfiddle.net/p510tuoy/27/

Comment: @wintersoft, если это у вас полный код тогда не удивительно что не работает. где у вас кладутся данные в локальное хранилище(localStorage.setItem)?

Comment: Заработало вот так https://jsfiddle.net/p510tuoy/56/